# Error of "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source" from PHP SOAP call

Tags: php, soap

I want to call a function in this web service (.Net):

http://cmr.rmto.ir/WCFServices/CMRService.svc?wsdl

in PHP i send all the variable and seems it is true! but the error is: 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source':

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source

Here is my code:

```
$params = array
(
    'T'=>  array
    (
        'CMRCategory'=>array
        (
            'CMRList'=> array
            (
                1 =>array
                (
                    'CMR' => array
                    (
                        'AttachmentDocuments'=>'AttachmentDocuments',
                        'BLNumber'=> '123654'  ,
                        'CMRItems'=> array
                        (
                            1 => array
                            (
                                'CMRItem'=> array
                                (
                                    'ClientID'=>'1',
                                    'FK_GoodClassID'=> 15,
                                    'FK_PackageTypeID'=> 102,
                                    'GoodsDescription'=> 'GoodsDescription',
                                    'GrossWeight'=> '5.5',
                                    'HSCODE'=> '1',
                                    'KotajNo'=> 'KotajNo',
                                    'Marks'=> 'Marks',       
                                    'NetWeight'=> '5.5',        
                                    'Quantity'=> '5.5',        
                                    'StatisticalNumber'=> 'StatisticalNumber',      
                                    'Volume'=>'5.5' 
                                ),
                            ),
                        ),
                        'CarnetTirNo'=> 'CarnetTirNo',
                        'ClientID'  => '1' ,
                        'Consignee'  => array
                        (

                                'Description'=>'Description',
                                'FK_CountryID'=>2
                                                    ),
                        'GoodsDescription' =>'GoodsDescription'  ,
                        'IssueDate'=>   '2013-06-09 12:03',
                        'LoadingDate'=>  '2013-06-09 12:03',
                        'Notify'=>   array
                        (

                                'Description'=>'Description',
                                'FK_CountryID'=>2

                        ),
                        'PlaceOfDischarge'=>   array
                        (
                                'Description'=>'Description',
                                'FK_CountryID'=>2

                        ),
                        'PlaceOfIssue'=>   array
                        (
                                'Description'=>'Description',
                                'FK_CountryID'=>2

                        ),
                        'PlaceOfLoading'=>   array
                        (

                                'Description'=>'Description',
                                'FK_CountryID'=>2

                        ),
                        'PlaceOfReceipt'=>   array
                        (

                                'Description'=>'Description',
                                'FK_CountryID'=>2

                        ),
                        'PrintSerialNo'=>  'PrintSerialNo',
                        'ReceiptDate'=>  '2013-06-09 12:03',
                        'ReferenceNo'=>  'ReferenceNo',
                        'Remark'=>  'Remark',
                        'Shipper'=> array
                        (

                                'Description'=>'Description',
                                'FK_CountryID'=>2

                        ),
                        'TotalWeight'=>  '12.6',
                    ),
                ),

            ),
            'ClientID'=> 2,
            'DocumentNo'=>'DocumentNo',
            'Driver'  => array
            (

                'Description'=>'Description',
                'FK_CountryID'=>2,
                'ExternalID'=>6,
                'FatherNameE'=> 'FatherNameE',
                'FatherNameP'=>'FatherNameP',
                'LastNameE'=> 'LastNameE',
                'LastNameP'=> 'LastNameP',
                'LicenceNo'=> 'LicenceNo',
                'MotherNameE'=> 'MotherNameE',
                'MotherNameP'=> 'MotherNameP',
                'NameE'=> 'NameE',
                'NameP'=> 'NameP',
                'PassportNo'=> 'PassportNo'

            ),
            'FK_InputBorderID'  =>1,
            'FK_NationalityID'  =>3,
            'FK_OutputBorderID'  =>1,
            'FK_TransportTypeID' =>1,
            'HashData'  =>'',
            'LeaveDate'  =>'2013-12-14',
            'Number'  =>'25454',
            'Signature'  =>'',
            'Truck'=> array
            (

                'ExternalID'=>'ExternalID',
                'FK_CountryID'=> 10,
                'TransitNo'=> 'tran13',
                'TruckNo'=> 'TruckNo',

            )
        ),

    ),
);
    $client = new SoapClient('http://cmr.rmto.ir/WCFServices/CMRService.svc?wsdl');
        $res=$client->__call('GetHash',array('parameters' => $params));
var_dump($res);
```